# 2 Navigations bar on FlipsideViewController of Utility Template

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have created a TableView in FlipsideViewController. I can see the table but the problem is that on FlipsideViewController i have to navaigations bars. on top is a blue bar without any button and under it a black bar with done button on it.

I want to remove that blue one, created automatically when i added TableView to the nib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing the navigation bar before moving to other View

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        .........
}
```

Hiding the navigation bar on FlipSideViewController

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```